Visual Studio Installer, list of apps
How can I determine which "instance" is the one where the problem occurred and remove it from the _Instances folder here:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages_Instances

I have attempted to install VS2019 Enterprise but it fails but I was successful installing VS2019 Professional.
This is my _Instances folder:


You can open state.json file under your VS Instances folder(e.g:63d13afa) and input keyword title/buildVersion. The detailed information about this instance are displayed.
"buildVersion":"17.11.35222.181",
"title":"Visual Studio Build Tools 2022",
"installationPath":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools",

Besides, i suggest you uninstall Visual Studio via VS Installer -> Uninstall instead of manually deletion when you encountered installation errors.
For more information, please read the doc:
Uninstall by using Visual Studio Installer
